# SQL Server - Select multiple Columns Group By 1 Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have looked at many examples of selecting many columns but only grouping by 1 column and mine seem to give me duplicate results. See below I would like to select  all the columns in my table but would like to only `GROUP BY` `VehicleId`. On the screenshot you'll see that the results are actually not grouped by `VehicleId`.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Try 1:

```
SELECT 
    h.*,

    TotalFines = 1,
    TotalIncidents = 1,
    TotalVehicleAllocations = 1,
    TotalVehicleConditions = 1,
    TotalMileageApplications = 1
FROM
(
    SELECT h1.VehicleId FROM [dbo].[VehicleHistory] h1 GROUP BY h1.VehicleId
) GroupedList
INNER JOIN [dbo].[VehicleHistory] h ON GroupedList.VehicleId=h.VehicleId
ORDER BY
    h.VehicleId;
```

Try 2:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM VehicleHistory t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT VehicleId FROM VehicleHistory GROUP BY VehicleId
)   t2
ON t1.VehicleId=t2.VehicleId
```

Both queries produce the same results with duplicate rows for each VehicleId as per below:

[image]

Here's my expected results below. The results are a query produced by Entity Framework. But I would like to rewrite the linq query into T-SQL:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your expected results?

Comment: @forpas, I have added how the results should look like.. I am trying to rewrite an Entity Framework Linq Query into a T-SQL query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are gtouping in subquery (which would be same as `SELECT DISTINCT h1.VehicleId FROM [dbo].[VehicleHistory] h1`):

```
SELECT h1.VehicleId FROM [dbo].[VehicleHistory] h1 GROUP BY h1.VehicleId
```

and then you are joining in on that column, which can cause duplicates to occur (you have duplicate IDs in `VehicleHistory`).

All you need to do is:

```
SELECT VehicleId,
       MAX(DateUpdated) DateUpdated, --or other aggregate function
       --rest of your columns in appropriate aggreagte functions
FROM VehicleHistory
GROUP BY VehicleId
```

Comment: Yes that produces expected results, but is that the best approach, adding `MAX` on all other columns?

Comment: @Morgs You can use whatever you need, that depends on you and cannot be thought as "best approach"", because it depends.